# iOS - UIView Doesn't resize in landscape

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, resize, landscape

something really weird it's happening to me (at least weird for me) 
I have a view controller (fileManagerViewController) the UI of this is basically an empty view
with a toolbar on top. I made this UI with IB. on the toolbar i have some buttons, two of those buttons are used to switch between two views. The UI for the two views that I've to switch was made by code.

- Inside the viewDidLoad of FileManagerViewController I wrote this

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  fileManagerTableView = [[FileManagerTableView alloc] init];
  fileManagerGridView  = [[FileManagerGridView alloc] init];
  self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
                              |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
  self.view.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
  self.view addSubview:fileManagerTableView.view];
  [self.view addSubview:fileManagerGridView.view];
  [fileManagerTableView.view setHidden:YES];
}
```

- those are the two loadView methods

```
    -(void) loadView {
        CGRect fileGridViewFrame  = CGRectMake(0.0, 50.0, 1024,768);
 fileGridView = [[[AQGridView alloc] 
                              initWithFrame:fileGridViewFrame] 
                               autorelease];  

 fileGridView.dataSource=self;
 fileGridView.delegate=self;
 fileGridView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|
                                       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
 fileGridView.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
 fileGridView.bounces;
 fileGridView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]]];
 [self.fileGridView reloadData];
 self.view = fileGridView;
}
```

```
    -(void) loadView {
        CGRect fileTableViewFrame  = CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 1024,768);
 fileGridView = [[[UITableView alloc] 
                              initWithFrame:fileTableViewFrame] 
                               autorelease];  

 fileGridView.dataSource=self;
 fileGridView.delegate=self;
 fileGridView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|
                                       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
 fileGridView.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
 fileGridView.bounces;
 fileGridView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]]];
 [self.fileGridView reloadData];
 self.view = fileGridView;
}
```

the result is, as i said weird, if the app start in portrait mode all works as I expect the two view s are rendered well in portrait and landscape mode. If the app is started with the device in landscape orientation the views don't fill the entire screen. Have a look a this
[screenshot](http://img88.imageshack.us/i/schermata20110127a16553.jpg/)

Answer (score 0):

Inside of IB, in the layout controls, play with the resize controls. To access the said controls, open the third tab in inspector (Cmd+3)

Also, inside of your viewWillAppear method, call setNeedsDisplay on your view.

Comment: what do you mean with play? the only nib file I have has only one plain empty view with a tool bar, the controller act as a container for my subviews that i add by code

Comment: Try different configurations. I am on iPhone now. I'll try to get more info when I'm on a computer later.

Comment: working with IB didn't produce any result. The subviews doesn't resize correctly. I've tried to increase the height of the views in the loadView method, and the gap disappeared. But this don't make any sense to me.